# Ambiguous reference to Func

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I'm using ReSharper 5.1 and Visual Studio 2010.

If I create a new Portable Class Library project and insert the following:

```
using System;

public interface TestInterface<T>
{
    void FindAll(Func<T> f);
}
```

ReSharper highlights the reference to 'Func' as an ambiguous reference.  Selecting 'Go to declaration' takes me to a choice of

- public delegate TResult Func<out TResult>(), from mscorlib 4.0.0.0

or

- public delegate TResult Func<TResult>(), from System.Core 2.0.5.0

However, the C# compiler builds this code successfully.  Suspending ReSharper and selecting 'Go To Definition' indicates that the actual definition being picked up is from System.Core.dll, v4.0.30319

Why is ReSharper getting confused?

The problem does not happen using a standard C# class library project type, only with a portable class library project type.

I noticed this problem while examining the source code of the [C5 Generic Collection Library
for C# and CLI](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/)

Comment: Does the problem manifest with ReSharper 6.0?  If not, I'd just file a bug.  If it compiles, then R# is clearly in the wrong.

Comment: Good question.  I installed ReSharper 6.0 - problem solved. Thank-you! With version 6.0 I'm a bit concerned about the big CPU spikes during editing though.

Comment: well, R6 is very disappointing in terms of performance.  The JetBrains folks know about it and promise it'll all be fixed in 6.1, and the EAP for that has been in the works for some time.  It was supposed to come out in mid-September, but it's now mid-October and no signs of that, to say nothing of an actual 6.1 release.  It's annoying -- and should be embarrassing for them -- that they haven't at least provided some intermediate bugfix releases to alleviate the problems.  If 6.1 isn't much improved, I'm going to take my money elsewhere.

Comment: With ReSharper 6.1.37.86, same issue continues for me.